# How can keep the screen layout after turning off the screens with a DELL D3100 Docking Station?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, hdmi

## System Specs

Ubuntu Version: 22.04.2 LTS
Tiling Window Manager: I am using i3WM
Docking station: DELL D3100

I have this monitor arrangement in the DELL D3100 Docking Station:

[image: arandr arrangement]

Where:

1. DP-0: Laptop Screen
2. HDMI-0: 70" Samsung
3. DVI-I-1-1: 32" Samsung
4. DVI-I-2-2: 32" Samsung

This results in a Screen Layout as shown in this screenshot.

[image: original-screen-layout]

## The problem

When I turn off the screens, and turn them on again after some minutes, let's say: if I leave my workplace to go for lunch or something, when returning, the 32" HDMI are inverted as shown in the next screenshot.

[image: inverted-screens]

Nevertheless, if I take a screenshot again, the screenshot shows the monitor arrangement and the image in the monitors is perfectly as I arranged them.

[image]

I think this is something the Dell D3100 Docking Station is not handling well when the screens are turned off but I would like to know if there's a way to keep the monitors arranged as if they were turned on.

## What I have tried

I have tried reducing the brightness in the monitors instead of turning them off but this won't work with a remote digital assistant like Alexa or Google Assistant. Let's say: If I am going out for a longer time than expected, I simply use my cellphone to ask Alexa to turn off the screens remotely.

### Scripts

The original xrandr script to arrange the screens currently has this:

### normallayout.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1080x0 --rotate normal --output DP-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1720x1440 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output DP-2 --off --output DVI-I-4-4 --off --output DVI-I-3-3 --off --output DVI-I-2-2 --off --output DVI-I-1-1 --off
sleep 1
cp /home/geppettvs/.config/i3/config-normal /home/geppettvs/.config/i3/config
DISPLAY=:1 xmacroplay -d 20 < i3macro.xmacro
sleep 1
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1080x0 --rotate normal --output DP-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1720x1440 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output DP-2 --off --output DVI-I-4-4 --off --output DVI-I-3-3 --off --output DVI-I-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x600 --rotate right --output DVI-I-2-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3640x600 --rotate left
```

When the 32" screens are rotated, I am inverting the status on the 32" screens by using a similar script as follows:

### inverted.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1080x0 --rotate normal --output DP-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1720x1440 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output DP-2 --off --output DVI-I-4-4 --off --output DVI-I-3-3 --off --output DVI-I-2-2 --off --output DVI-I-1-1 --off
sleep 1

cp /home/geppettvs/.config/i3/config-invert /home/geppettvs/.config/i3/config
DISPLAY=:1 xmacroplay -d 20 < i3macro.xmacro

xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1440 --pos 1080x0 --rotate normal --output DP-0 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1720x1440 --rotate normal --output DP-1 --off --output DP-2 --off --output DVI-I-4-4 --off --output DVI-I-3-3 --off --output DVI-I-2-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x600 --rotate right --output DVI-I-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3640x600 --rotate left
```

Please do notice this inverted.sh script contains a call to copy a new i3 config file, which contains the required key bindings to create a similar experience.

The results, nevertheless, are far from creating a similar user experience. Moving between the monitors is somehow unnatural and difficult to use, compared with the normal layout behavior.

Thanks in advance.